# Delete Request in react not deleting

Tags: node.js, reactjs

So I am trying to do a delete method in React on the front end UI I get the 200 ok request but I may be doing something wrong so here is my front end and back end code and screen shot of the Ui

[image]

```
 front end




import React, {Component} from 'react';
    import './App.css';
    import axios from 'axios';
    export default class TableRow extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
     this.deletestudent = this.deletestudent.bind(this);
    }
       deletestudent(student_id) {

     axios.post('http://localhost:3200/students/deleteStudent')
     .then(console.log('Student Deleted'))
     .catch(err => console.log(err));
   }
  render(){
    return(
      <tr>
            <td>{this.props.object._id}</td>
            <td>{this.props.object.role_num} </td>
             <td>{this.props.object.first_name}</td>
            <td>{this.props.object.last_name}</td>
            <td><button className = 'btn-btn-danger'>Update</button> </td>
            <td><button onClick={this.deletestudent} className = 'btn-btn-danger' color='blue'> Remove</button></td>
     </tr>
    );
  }
}
```

back end

```
second.post('/students/deleteStudent', (req, res) => {

   res.send('delete student'+req.body._id);
    try {
     db.collection('students').deleteOne( { "_id" : ObjectID(req.body._id) } );
  } catch (e) {
   console.log(e);
  }
     res.send('delete student');
  });
```

Also when I click on the response I get delete student undefined do I need to change my back end I know I need to delete by id but can not figure out how

Comment: You are not sending student id to be deleted to backend

Comment: ok then you want me to do /:id in the back end

Comment: axios.post('/user', {
    firstName: 'Fred',
    lastName: 'Flintstone'
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });

Comment: @RajatDhoot but is their anything I need to change in my back end tho

Comment: @RajatDhoot I wanna delete by id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two correction needed here.

1. Pass `_.id` as `student_id` to `deletestudent` function or use it from props.
2. Pass that `student_id` in your axios post call.

**CODE**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';
export default class TableRow extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.deletestudent = this.deletestudent.bind(this);
    }
    deletestudent() {
        axios.post('http://localhost:3200/students/deleteStudent', {
            '_id': this.props.object._id
        })
            .then(console.log('Student Deleted'))
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <tr>
                <td>{this.props.object._id}</td>
                <td>{this.props.object.role_num} </td>
                <td>{this.props.object.first_name}</td>
                <td>{this.props.object.last_name}</td>
                <td><button className='btn-btn-danger'>Update</button> </td>
                <td><button onClick={this.deletestudent} className='btn-btn-danger' color='blue'> Remove</button></td>
            </tr>
        );
    }
}
```